I have an AuthGuard implements using Auth0 for angular , that keep redirecting
I have an angular app where I have an account component. On the account component I have an AuthGuard and i am using Auth0 for authentication. When the user is logged out, everything works as it should where they are led to the login url to login, When the login is a success they are redirected to the provided url redirect. But when I try accessing the component at that point the app just keeps routing back to the redirect url.
Here is my code
The AuthGuard
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, take, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.isLoading$.pipe(
      tap((loading) => console.log('AuthGuard: isLoading$', loading)),
      filter((loading) => !loading), // Ensure the loading state is false before proceeding
      switchMap(() => this.auth.isAuthenticated$), // Check if the user is authenticated
      tap((loggedIn) => {
        if (!loggedIn) {
          console.log('AuthGuard: Not authenticated, redirecting to login');
          this.auth.loginWithRedirect({ appState: { target: state.url } });
        } else {
          console.log('AuthGuard: Authenticated, access granted');
        }
      }),
      map((loggedIn) => loggedIn) // Return the loggedIn state to allow or deny access
    );
  }
}

The app routing module
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }, // Renamed 'places' to 'map'
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }, // Renamed 'places' to 'map'
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }


The App Module
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // Import FormsModule
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; // Import HttpClientModule for HTTP requests
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { OpenComponent } from './open/open.component';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';
import { CustomModalComponent } from './custom-modal/custom-modal.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';



import { AuthModule } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';

import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
register();


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
# All declarations
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      domain: 'Auth0-Domain',
      clientId: 'Auth0-ClientId',
      authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin
      },
      cacheLocation: 'localstorage',
  useRefreshTokens: false // Optional: enables silent authentication
    }),
    IonicModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA], // Add this line
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

The App component looks like this. This is where all the navigation is located that triggers the router outlet.
<!-- <nav class="navbar is-fixed-top"></nav> -->
<div class="tab-bar">
  <button [ngClass]="{'active': currentRoute === '/home'}" (click)="navigate('/home')">
    <i class="material-icons">home</i>
  </button>
  
  <button [ngClass]="{'active': currentRoute === '/account'}" (click)="navigate('/account')">
    <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
    </button>


</div>

  <div class="main-content">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>


Also in the Auth0 Dashbboard setting for the app
Allowed Callback URL is : http://localhost:4200
Allowed Web Origin : http://localhost:4200
This is very odd to me. I am not sure how to proceed. I know the Auth Is working since I could check the Auth0 dashboard and the logs say the login is a success.
What do I change here ?
--Edit--
I tried this approach after a tutorial. It did not work either
    <button *ngIf="_auth.isAuthenticated$ | async; else outBtn" (click)="_auth.logout()">
      <i class="material-icons">logout</i>
      </button>
<ng-template #outBtn>
  <button (click)="_auth.loginWithPopup()">
    <i class="material-icons">login</i>
    </button>

and the TS is
  constructor(private router: Router, public _auth: AuthService) {
}

Seems like auth always reads the authentication state as Unauthenticated. Seriously odd.


You can return an URL Tree in your guard in case or user is not auth and need to be redirect, somethink like:
 return this.auth.isLoading$.pipe(
              tap((loading) => console.log('AuthGuard: isLoading$', loading)),
              filter((loading) => !loading), // Ensure the loading state is false before proceeding
              switchMap(() => this.auth.isAuthenticated$), // Check if the user is authenticated
              map((loggedIn) => {
                if (!loggedIn) {
                  return  this.auth.loginWithRedirect({ appState: { target: state.url } });
                } else {
                  return true
                }
              }),
            );


I went on to change my whole approach after looking at a tutorial. so now in the app component where i have my navbar i have these 2 buttons

    <button *ngIf="_auth.isAuthenticated$ | async; else outBtn" (click)="_auth.logout()">
      <i class="material-icons">logout</i>
      </button>
<ng-template #outBtn>
  <button (click)="_auth.loginWithPopup()">
    <i class="material-icons">login</i>
    </button>

and the TS is
  constructor(private router: Router, public _auth: AuthService) {


the button never changes, _auth is always reading as unauthenticated.

Is an issue with the observable, maybe isLoading$ never set to false or isAuthenticated$ dont emit true in you switchmap ? put some consolelog in your pipe
